# VBScript Faxing multiple documents array issue

Tags: arrays, vbscript, fax

I am having trouble with the FaxDoc.Bodies function.  I get the error "Methods data should be passed in a one-dimensional zero-based array of strings."

I have tried everything I can think of, from using array() directly on the FaxDoc.Bodies element.  Any ideas?

```
Dim strJobIds
Dim STAttach(1)
'On Error Resume Next 
Set FaxServer = WScript.CreateObject("FAXCOMEX.FaxServer") 

WScript.Echo "FaxServer created"  
FaxServer.Connect "" 


Set FaxDoc = WScript.CreateObject("FAXCOMEX.FaxDocument") 



STAttach(0)="chili.txt"
STAttach(1)="sugarcookies.txt"


FaxDoc.Bodies=STAttach

FaxDoc.DocumentName = "My First Fax" 

FaxDoc.Recipients.Add ("15555551234") 

FaxDoc.Sender.Email = "bob@xyz.com" 
FaxDoc.Sender.Name = "Bob" 
FaxDoc.Sender.FaxNumber = "15555555678"

'    Optionally, Use FaxDoc.CoverPage and FaxDoc.CoverPageType to specify a cover page 
'    FaxDoc.CoverPage = generic 
'    FaxDoc.CoverPageType = 2 

'    Optionally, you can control banner in outbound faxes 
FaxServer.Folders.OutgoingQueue.Branding = True
FaxServer.Folders.OutgoingQueue.Save     '      Make the change persistent 
'    Optionally, use FaxServer.Folders.OutgoingQueue.Retries and 
'    FaxServer.Folders.OutgoingQueue.RetryDelay to control retries 

'    Submit the document to the connected fax server and get back the job ID. 
strJobIds=""
JobID = FaxDoc.ConnectedSubmit2(FaxServer, strJobIds) 

WScript.Echo "FaxDoc.ConnectedSubmit success"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It asks for an array and using the semicolon separator does not work and returns the same error messages.

I did, however, find a solution using a VBA Console Application instead of VBScript.  My code is as follows:

```
Module Module1
    Function DecodeToDocArray(ByVal inputDocListString As String, ByRef numDocuments As Integer, ByRef bRetVal As Boolean) As String()
        bRetVal = False
        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputDocListString)) Then
            Return Nothing
        End If
        Dim docArray As String()
        Dim strDelimiter As String
        Dim delimiter As Char()

        docArray = Nothing
        strDelimiter = ";"
        delimiter = strDelimiter.ToCharArray()
        docArray = inputDocListString.Split(delimiter)
        numDocuments = docArray.GetLength(0)
        bRetVal = True
        Return docArray
    End Function
    Sub Main()



        Dim retVal As Boolean
        Dim numDocs As Integer
        Dim docArray As String()
        Dim strDocList As String = "chili.txt;sugarcookies.txt"
        MsgBox(strDocList)
        numDocs = 0
        docArray = DecodeToDocArray(strDocList, numDocs, retVal)
        If ((docArray.GetLength(0) = 0) Or (retVal = False)) Then
            System.Console.WriteLine("DecodeToDocArray failed")
            retVal = False
            MsgBox("End")
            End
        End If

        Dim FaxDoc = CreateObject("FAXCOMEX.FaxDocument")
        Dim FaxServer = CreateObject("FAXCOMEX.FaxServer")
        FaxServer.Connect("")

        MsgBox("test")
        FaxDoc.Bodies = docArray
        FaxDoc.Sender.LoadDefaultSender()
        FaxDoc.Recipients.Add("15555551234", "TestUser")
        Dim strJobIds As Object
        strJobIds = Nothing

        FaxDoc.ConnectedSubmit2(FaxServer, strJobIds)

        MsgBox("sent")

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Nice find and thank you for posting the solution! Maybe you could flag your answer as the correct answer, so it is easier to find for other people with the same issue.

Comment: I plan to, but it says I have to wait a day before I can.

Answer (score 0):

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa359008%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you should pass the documents as a string with the documents separated by a semi colon:

```
FaxDoc.Bodies = "chili.txt;sugarcookies.txt"
```